# Bring Tavern on the Meta to meta.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

[Our lovely chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) is no more! All I get is a redirect to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackoverflow.com.

Could the Tavern be extracted from wherever it went and get sent over to MSE? <sub>Remember to bring the unicorns too.</sub>

*Ahem*, @TimPost, not completed (at least for me) (click image to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: ZOMG THE FIRST STATUS-COMPLETED IS MINE! MIIIIIINNNNNNEEEEE!

Comment: @TimPost Um nope (see edit)

Comment: It _is_ there, but we lacked a DNS entry, it should sort out for you shortly (also, please try incognito / flushing cache)